# Pointer Exception while getting RGB values from (video) frame Intel Realsense

Tags: c++, pointers, rgb, intel, realsense

I'm trying to get the different RGB values from a frame with the Realsense SDK. This is for a 3D depth camera with RGB. According to https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/3364 I need to use

```
int i = 100, j = 100; // fetch pixel 100,100
rs2::frame rgb = ...
auto ptr = (uint8_t*)rgb.get_data();
auto stride = rgb.as<rs2::video_frame>().stride();
cout << "R=" << ptr[3*(i * stride + j)];
cout << ", G=" << ptr[3*(i * stride + j) + 1];
cout << ", B=" << ptr[3*(i * stride + j) + 2];
```

In my code I'm getting a pointer exception if I want to get the values for pixel **(x,y)=1000,1000**. With **(x,y)=100,100** it works every time... Error: `Exception thrown: read access violation. ptr was 0x11103131EB9192A.`

[image]

I set the `enable_stream` to `cfg.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_COLOR, WIDTH_COLOR_FRAME, HEIGTH_COLOR_FRAME, RS2_FORMAT_RGB8, 15);` where in the .h file are:

```
#define WIDTH_COLOR_FRAME   1920
#define HEIGTH_COLOR_FRAME  1080
```

This is my code. Maybe it has something to do with the `RS2_FORMAT_RGB8`?

```
frameset frames = pl.wait_for_frames();
frame color = frames.get_color_frame();

uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)color.get_data();
int stride = color.as<video_frame>().get_stride_in_bytes();

int i = 1000, j = 1000; // fetch pixel 100,100

cout << "R=" << int(ptr[3 * (i * stride + j)]);
cout << ", G=" << int(ptr[3 * (i * stride + j) + 1]);
cout << ", B=" << int(ptr[3 * (i * stride + j) + 2]);
cout << endl;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stride is in bytes (length of row in bytes), multiplication with 3 is not required.

```
cout << "  R= " << int(ptr[i * stride + (3*j)    ]);
cout << ", G= " << int(ptr[i * stride + (3*j) + 1]);
cout << ", B= " << int(ptr[i * stride + (3*j) + 2]);
```

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks! However I think the '3' stands at the wrong location right?
`cout << "  R= " << int(ptr[i * stride + (3*j)    ]);
cout << ", G= " << int(ptr[i * stride + (3*j) + 1]);
cout << ", B= " << int(ptr[i * stride + (3*j) + 2]);`

This because otherwise it will mix in the RGB values from the previous pixel.. Thanks for your help! Now it's clear

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and even with the last answers I still got segfaults.

I found out that when you do

uint8_t *ptr = color.get_data()

the realsense sdk won't increase/track some internal reference and the pointer went invalid after some time, causing the segfaults.
my Fix is copy the content to a local buffer.

- malloc new buffer with RGB size.
- right after get_data() copy data to the new buffer.

that fixed all my issues.
all the best.